# Using AJAX to display how many of the current product is currently in the shopping cart

Tags: javascript, ajax, woocommerce

really hoping someone can help me out here.

What I want to achieve is to show a little icon displaying how many of the current product is in the shopping cart. E.g. user is browsing the product page "fresh oranges", the user adds 2 fresh oranges to the cart then I want to display "2" somewhere on the product page. Here is my code:

```
<?php foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
$_product = $values['data'];    
if( $_product->id == get_the_ID() ) { ?>
    <div class="quantity-in-cart">
        <span><?php echo $values['quantity'] ?></span>
    </div>
<?php } } ?>
```

It's working if you refresh the product page, but since I'm using AJAX so the whole page doesn't refresh every time the user adds a product, I need this quantity field to update as more of this product is added to the cart.

If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it, any questions or if none of what I wrote makes sense please let me know.

Comment: There's no ajax in your current code. Do you you want to send an AJAX request to a background php script that takes the order and on success your response updates the quantity in the shopping cart? The other approach is that you just update the quantity and send it for processing on checkout or when navigating away from that page (for which you don't need ajax [initially])

Comment: Hi datafunk - I know there's no AJAX there right now, that's just an example of the code that gets the quantity of the current product ID from the woocommerce cart. What I'm looking to do is re-check the quantity when the user adds more of the product to the cart. Thanks for the response. Edit: Should clarify that all of this is to run on the product page. I just want to show how many of the product is currently in the user's cart.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the shopping cart you mention, but conceptually this is how I'd go about it (option one of my initial comment):

```
<div class="quantity-in-cart">
    <span data-qty="0" id="qty">0</span>
</div>

<input type="number" value="0" step="1" id="add_qty">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var qty = $('#qty').data('qty');

$('#add_qty').on('click', function(event){
    $.ajax({
        url: "path/to/your/script.php",
    }).done(function() {
        $('#qty').attr('data-qty', $(this).val() );
        $('#qty').html( $(this).val() );
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain the reason why you downvoted my answer? I believe it addressed your question RE how to implement this method using AJAX

Comment: That wasn't me mate, I wouldn't do that as I am grateful that you took the time to try and help, looks like someone else did it. It doesn't really accomplish what I'm trying to achieve though as far as I can understand it. Someone with knowledge on how WooCommerce uses AJAX for its mini-cart would probably be able to take some code from there and modify it a little. If no one pops up with such a solution though I'm happy with the workaround I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround without needing to use AJAX which suits my needs.

Display the number of the current product in the cart in case the user comes back to the product page later. If empty, nothing will display.

```
<div class="quantity-in-cart">
<span><?php foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];    
    if( $_product->id == get_the_ID() ) { ?><?php echo $values['quantity'] ?>
<?php } } ?></span>
</div>
```

So if there are none of the current product in the cart, nothing will show up in that span. So I added this JS to add a 0:

```
$span = $(".quantity-in-cart span");
if($span.text() == ""){
    $span.text("0");
}
```

Now with a default value of 0 set in that span, if the user adds more of the current product to the cart, we can add the number in the span to the quantity number selected by the user via the add to cart form.

```
$(".description .add-to-cart .add_to_cart_button").click(function() {
    $('.quantity-in-cart span').text(parseInt($('.quantity-in-cart span').text()) + parseInt($('.quantity .qty').val()));
});
```

...And I'm happy with that. There's probably a better way to get a 0 in that span if there are none of the current product in the cart via php, but I'm not great with php. Just figured I'd share my workaround on the off chance someone is looking to achieve something similar. I would still be interested in seeing how to accomplish this properly using WooCommerce's AJAX functionality (there's probably some code from the mini-cart that could be used but I don't understand it well enough myself.)